# Why is apache bench not connecting when curl is?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin, puma, apachebench

I was using webrick in development and apache bench was working fine. Then I tried switching to thin and puma. With each of these, my app works fine with curl but apache bench can't connect.

```
curl http://localhost:4567/
[{"foo":"bar"}]
```

But ab fails:

```
➔ ab http://localhost:4567/
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1663405 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...apr_socket_recv: Connection refused (61)
```